# First Order ODE Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve an IVP with some difficulty. Actually, I'm having a problem just getting started. Problem:

$6y' - \frac{2}{y} = xy^4$

where

$y(0)=2, x>0$

To give you some context, I'm in a class which has thus far done Separable and  Bernoulli ODEs to solve problems like this. I can't see how one can get either method to work. For example, my first thought was to divide by $y^4$ and treat it like a Bernoulli ODE. However, you can never rearrange the problem to have a simplification of something like $v$ and $v'$, as the $y^{-1}$ in the problem causes issues with this.

Any guidance on what is the way to move forward on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this equation is not so easy to solve or we have a typo

Comment: I don't think it is possible to solve this with methods you know.

Comment: I feared this. Out of curiosity, you say "methods you know." Does that mean there is, and what is it?

Comment: Does that mean there is A METHOD, I meant to say

Comment: Some ODEs are very difficult, and it's not always clear what is solvable. Wolfram Alpha isn't finding it, so that's not a good sign.